# How does Microsoft Intune change settings, say Password Policy, leaving the registry values intact?

Tags: azure-active-directory, intune

How does microsoft intune changes password policies in enrolled windows 10 pc without changing any registry or group policy settings? When these settings are controlled by a domain controller the changes can be observed in registry or group policy which helps a compliance testing tool to figure out if the settings have been set as per guidelines. How is a compliance testing tool expected to test the settings when they are managed by intune?

Answer (score 0):

IF your devices is Azure AD join then there is no domain controller and it is directly joined to the Azure Active directory. In Intune you can create a compliance policy to manage your organizational resources. As part of your mobile device management (MDM) these settings are added to device configuration profile in Intune and then assigned to your windows 10 devices.

If you want to monitor the device compliance kindly check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/protect/compliance-policy-monitor) to get more information

If your machine is Hybrid Azure AD join then either you can have Configuration Manager standalone or co-management with Microsoft Intune. But for the password it will be on domain-controller only.

Comment: I am being the third party here who doesn't have access to azureAD or intune. The second party configured the win10 machine using intune and i am supposed to check if the win10 password policies are as per CIS guidelines.